# Comparing spatial patterns to on-average-distribution by averaging intervals that overlap in space

Tags: time-series, modeling, spatial

I am analyzing spatial patterns in vegetation structure across vegetation transects. I broke transects up into 3-m intervals that move across the transect (a moving window) 1-m at a time. So, the intervals in the analysis overlap in space. I think this is somewhat comparable to a time-series analysis as phenomena are related to previous phenomena in the time sequence. To be honest, I know very little about time series analyses. I want to compare patterns in the data to what is on average occurring on the transect. I am considering using a random-walk type approach. **My question is can I just average each interval together (so I would be averaging intervals that overlap in space) to compare to my transect data to detect spatial patterns?** Thanks in advance.

To explain what kind of data I have, I measured vegetation structure (i.e. shrub heights, grass height, shrub width, etc.) along line transects. I suspect there are patches of taller shrubs and patches of shorter shrubs. To evaluate if this is the case I wanted to compare measurements along transects (broken into moving window intervals to capture variation) to a scenario where shrub heights are randomly distributed (e.g. not patterned in patches). I was thinking a way to do this would be to compare transect measurements to the average shrub height witnessed across intervals.

Comment: It would be nice to know what kind of data you have and what you mean by a "pattern" so that we can decipher what it means to "average" an interval.